# spring security not working on preAuthorize

Tags: spring-security

Configuring Spring Security seems like such a dark art!

I am trying to implement method-level security. I have tried everything to get this method to fire it's preAuthorize.

Can anyone explain why the first method works fine and evaluates whatever expression is against it, but the second doesn't. In the logs I don't see any calls to the Security framework for that method (I've restarted the server maybe 20 times, and have tried various versions with and without any preAuthorize on the parent method)...

This is challenging, I've got no information to go by, no debug capability on the SPEL expression...I seem to be in this trial and error loop that's getting nowhere!

The second method is definitely entered because I can debug it and see the output in the logs.

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_REGISTERED_CUSTOMER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public void updateAddress(CustomerAddress customerAddress) {

        logger.entry();

        geocodingService.geoCodeAddress(customerAddress);

        if (customerAddress.getId() != null)
        {
            CustomerAddress oldAddress = customerAddressRepository.findForReference(customerAddress.getId());
            updateExistingAddress(customerAddress, oldAddress);
            customerSearchService.reindexCustomer(oldAddress.getCustomer(), true);
        }else
        {
            updateNewAddress(customerAddress);
            customerSearchService.reindexCustomer(customerAddress.getCustomer(), true);
        }
        logger.exit();
    }

    /**
     * A secured method for updating the existing address.
     * @param newAddress the new address
     * @param oldAddress the existing database address
     */
    @PreAuthorize("denyAll")
    public void updateExistingAddress(CustomerAddress newAddress, CustomerAddress oldAddress)
    {
        logger.entry();

        logger.debug("Updating an existing address.");


        oldAddress.mergeEdit(newAddress);
        saveAddress(oldAddress);

        logger.exit();
    }
```

Comment: And it should fail why? It is an internal method call, hence bypassing any proxied behavior you have. It will work if called externally...

Comment: The denyAll was just a test. I just figured that out too re: the proxies...I'm going to have to refactor so much code! Wow this is going to take weeks of work to fix :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M.Deinum stated proxies do get invoked with internal method calls. If you want this support you need to use AspectJ. You can find an example of using AspectJ in [xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/aspectj-xml) and [java config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples) within the samples.

Comment: it's okay, I'll just refactor the code to pass the database object down to the method from the Controller. Cheers.